# something about new php parameters

Tags: php

has a script obviously works in another location
but in the log says:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['

line 212:

```
$JABBER->username = explode("@",$jabber_sender)[0];
```

IMHO, this is a parameter of php, allowing the combination of structures, functions, arrays in one line. That is,
remodel is not necessary

```
$server = explode("@",$jabber_sender);
$JABBER->server[1];
```

Thx

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: AFAIK, the structure you're using is only available in later versions of PHP. If you're moving to an environment with an earlier version of PHP, functions like this will break.

Comment: tnx , will try on updated php version

Answer (score 3):

This is a PHP version issue. Accessing an array element after a function call such as in your example is supported in PHP 5.4 and is called "Array Dereferencing". When you put this code onto a server that is running a version of php older than 5.4 this syntax will not work and you will need to use the syntax as you demonstrated in your second example.

[PHP Docs Example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88)

[PHP 5.4 Changelog](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: @user2514964 If this answer helped you, please accept it using the checkmark icon to the left of this post.